# how to change background image on hover inside list and a link using css?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to change a picture that is nested inside  link that is nested inside a list.

My idea was using the picture as a background picture.
The problem is that except for the picture, I have written inside the `<li>` some text, and I just can't get my background-picture placed right according to the link and the list itself.

```
.solution-pic {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     width: 151px;
     height: 63px;    
     display:block;
     background: transparent url('http://s1.postimg.org/ysb0w71ej/solution_icon_personal_hover.png') center top no-repeat;
 }
```

You can find my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ronilitman/fhpqwccx/)

Comment: the question is not clear .. what do you want exactly

Comment: @Sarath sorry, I want that my background picture will be above the linked text

Comment: the image should hide text on hover right ?

Comment: @Sarath No, I just want that it will be placed above the text and when :hover to change the background image as I showed on my fiddle

Comment: @ronilitman would you like to use only css?

Comment: is this you need.. http://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/fhpqwccx/4/ ?

Comment: @itapi Yes, css only

Answer (score 1):

Use hover property to change image

```
   a:hover.solution-pic{
             margin-bottom: 10px;
             width: 151px;
             height: 63px;    
             display:block;
             background: transparent url('new img url') center top no-repeat;
         }
```

Comment: Yes I did, you can see on my fiddle that it worked. The problem is that the background image is not placed well according to the link

Comment: change your image size using paint or photoshop

Answer (score 0):

Just by your title, if you want to change something on hover, you have to use the :hover

```
//CHANGE BACKGROUND TO WHITE -Exclude the image
.solution-pic:hover {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width: 151px;
      height: 63px;    
      display:block;
      background:white;
}
```

But if you want to align it correctly, I would suggest to see some bootstrap CSS like the following

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-examples